# Replace whitespace in string with zeros

Tags: bash, shell

My file looks like:

```
BRRD P 14 1 812 7 32.82  
RESD P 14 1 812 7 32.97  

AZEP P 14 1112053 13.87  
AZHS P 14 1112053 14.18
```

I need to insert zeroes so it looks like:

```
BRRD P 1401081207 32.82  
RESD P 1401081207 32.97  

AZEP P 1401112053 13.87  
AZHS P 1401112053 14.18
```

So, the 3rd column should always be a string consisting of 10 characters. The problem is the missing zeros in the empty characters. I would like to replace the whitespace characters with zeros in the 3rd column.

I tried  `cat temp8 | sed 's/^ /0 /g' | sed 's/  $/  0/g' | sed 's/  / 0/g' > temp9`, but it ends up looking like:

```
BRRD P 1312211336 058.52  
RESD P 1312211336 058.72  
0 00  
AZCT P 131222 055 036.99  
AZFS P 131222 055 00 .0
```

I also considered inserting zeros at a certain row position, but the empty characters in column 3 are random.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '{val=$3; for (i=4; i<NF; i++) val = val "0" $i; print $1, $2, val, $NF}' file

BRRD P 1401081207 32.82
RESD P 1401081207 32.97

AZEP P 1401112053 13.87
AZHS P 1401112053 14.18
```

Answer (score 2):

Gnu awk and `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""; FIELDWIDTHS="7 10 6"} {gsub(/ /,"0",$2)} 1' file
BRRD P 1401081207 32.82
RESD P 1401081207 32.97

AZEP P 1401112053 13.87
AZHS P 1401112053 14.18

<--7--><---10---><--6->
```

Set the `FIELDWIDTHS` as above, and replace spaces in the second field with `0`s. `OFS` must be empty.

Answer (score -1):

Check below code.

```
x="1401081207 32.82"

echo "${x// /0}"
```

Syntax

```
${varName//Pattern/Replacement}
```

Comment: The desired output doesn't replace *all* whitespace with 0s.

Comment: wait a second let me try again

Comment: here is the output working on mine on above example 0000This0000is000000a000000test000bash